# struct first line is just an interface, what does it mean?

Tags: go

I come across this code in Go:

```
type Mytype struct {
  Interfacename
  var1  ClientInterface1
  var2  ClientInterface2
  id    int
}
```

What does that first field mean?

Comment: Thanks Flimzy for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**Mostly**, this is how some sort of inheritance (by composition rather than inheritance) is achieved in go. Check this out: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

This will grant the Outer type (`MyType`) access to this inner type's Receiver methods (the assigned struct{} since this is an interface).

From [Go Effective](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html):

> There's an important way in which embedding differs from subclassing.
>   When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the
>   outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is
>   the inner type, not the outer one

Thanks **@Flimzy** and **@md2perpe**

**Also**, this defines an *anonymous field*, for which the variable name will be the same as its type name.

Comment: oh ya, Kitchen in the example is not a type interface

Comment: In the language of object orientation: this is how to do inheritance in Go.